# Переставить элементы массив php в другой последовательности

Tags: php, сортировка

Есть вот такой массив:

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Название] => Техника
                [Код] => e2553780
                [КодРодителя] => 
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [Название] => Тележки ручные
                [Код] => 8b3c2d19
                [КодРодителя] => 8b3c2d10
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [Название] => Тележки ручные ТП
                [Код] => 2e4744ac
                [КодРодителя] => 8b3c2d19
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [Название] => Тележки двухколесные
                [Код] => 2e4744ae
                [КодРодителя] => 8b3c2d19
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [Название] => Тележки
                [Код] => 8b3c2d10
                [КодРодителя] => e2553780
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [Название] => Столы подъемные
                [Код] => 8b3c2d11
                [КодРодителя] => e2553780
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [Название] => Штабелеры
                [Код] => 8b3c2d12
                [КодРодителя] => e2553780
            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [Название] => Весовое оборудование
                [Код] => 8b3c2d16
                [КодРодителя] => 
            )

    )
```

Как пересобрать массив, чтобы получилось такое дерево:

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Название] => Техника
                [Код] => e2553780
                [КодРодителя] => 
                [Подразделы] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [Название] => Тележки
                                [Код] => 8b3c2d10
                                [КодРодителя] => e2553780
                                [Подразделы] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [Название] => Тележки ручные
                                                [Код] => 8b3c2d19
                                                [КодРодителя] => 8b3c2d10
                                                [Подразделы] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [0] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [Название] => Тележки ручные ТП
                                                                [Код] => 2e4744ac
                                                                [КодРодителя] => 8b3c2d19
                                                            )

                                                        [1] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [Название] => Тележки двухколесные
                                                                [Код] => 2e4744ae
                                                                [КодРодителя] => 8b3c2d19
                                                            )

                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [Название] => Столы подъемные
                                [Код] => 8b3c2d11
                                [КодРодителя] => e2553780
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [Название] => Штабелеры
                                [Код] => 8b3c2d12
                                [КодРодителя] => e2553780
                            )

                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [Название] => Весовое оборудование
                [Код] => 8b3c2d16
                [КодРодителя] => 
            )

    )
```

Comment: В чем у вас сложность случилась или вы просто ждёте решение за вас?

Comment: каким образом "тележки ручные" и "тележки ручные ТП" являются подразделами у "тележек" ? Код родителя правильный ?

Comment: @Alex, ваша  правда. Была ошибка, исправил.

Comment: ну видимо сначала нужно собрать элементы верхнего уровня. Потом брать по одному элементу из изначального массива и искать ему рекурсией родителя в этом новом, при совпадении ставить его на нужное место и удалять из первоначального. Так пока не закончатся элементы

Answer (score 0):

По предложенному алгоритму собрал элементы верхнего уровня в отдельный в новый массив $arNew, удалив их из старого массива $arOld

```
   Array
        (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Название] => Складская техника
                [Код] => e2553780-300b-11e3-afc3-50e54942c94a
                [КодРодителя] => 
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [Название] => Весовое оборудование
                [Код] => 8b3c2d16-9b04-11e6-9a02-00155defec04
                [КодРодителя] => 
            )
        )
```

Далее пишу функцию, которая будет рекурсией находить родителя в новом массиве из старого

```
function parents(&$arNew, &$arOld)
    {

        foreach ($arOld as $key => $arr1)
        {
            foreach ($arNew as $k => $arr2) 
            {
                 if($arr1['КодРодителя'] == $arr2['Код']) {
                    $arNew[$k]['Подразделы'][] = $arr1;
                    unset($arOld[$key]);
                 }
            }
        }
    }
```

А как сделать рекурсию ума не приложу.

Comment: не является ответом, перенесите содержимое в поле вопроса (т.к. это то как Вы пытались решить проблему), а данный ответ удалите.

Answer (score 0):

рекурсия должна иметь внутри условие по которому происходит выход из функции (случай когда больше нет подэлементов в текущем родительском элементе) иначе она должна вызывать сама себя еще раз но с подэлементом в качестве параметра вместо текущего элемента и возвращать следующий найденный подэлемент

немного сумбурно но в принципе как-то так должно быть:

parent
 - subparent
 - subparent
 -- subparent
 -- subparent

`func(parent) {
subparent = parent->getSubparent();
if (no subelements) { return };
return func(subelement);
}`

Answer (score 0):

Вот такая получилась функция:

```
function recursion(&$arSections, $root = null) {
    $arr = array();
    foreach($arSections as $child => $parent) {

        if($parent['КодРодителя'] == $root['Код']) {
            unset($arSections[$child]);

            $arr[] = array(
                $parent,
                recursion($arSections, $parent)
            );
        }
    }
    return empty($arr) ? null : $arr;    
}
```

Результат немного не такой получается:

```
  $result = recursion($arRes['sections']);
//не совсем такой вывод как по условию.
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [Название] => Складская техника
                        [Код] => e2553780-300b-11e3-afc3-50e54942c94a
                        [КодРодителя] => 
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [Название] => Тележки
                                        [Код] => 8b3c2d10-9b04-11e6-9a02-00155defec04
                                        [КодРодителя] => e2553780-300b-11e3-afc3-50e54942c94a
                                    )

                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [Название] => Тележки ручные
                                                        [Код] => 8b3c2d19-9b04-11e6-9a02-00155defec04
                                                        [КодРодителя] => 8b3c2d10-9b04-11e6-9a02-00155defec04
                                                    )

                                                [1] => Array
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($inArray as $value){
        if (!$value['КодРодителя']){
            $outArray[$value['Код']] = $value;
        }else{
            $outArray[$value['КодРодителя']]['Подразделы'][$value['Код']] = $value;
        }
    }

    echo'<pre>'; print_r($outArray); die;
```

Резултать:

```
Array
(
[e2553780] => Array
    (
        [Название] => Техника
        [Код] => e2553780
        [Подразделы] => Array
            (
                [8b3c2d10] => Array
                    (
                        [Название] => Тележки
                        [Код] => 8b3c2d10
                        [КодРодителя] => e2553780
                    )

                [8b3c2d11] => Array
                    (
                        [Название] => Столы подъемные
                        [Код] => 8b3c2d11
                        [КодРодителя] => e2553780
                    )

                [8b3c2d12] => Array
                    (
                        [Название] => Штабелеры
                        [Код] => 8b3c2d12
                        [КодРодителя] => e2553780
                    )

            )

    )

[8b3c2d10] => Array
    (
        [Подразделы] => Array
            (
                [8b3c2d19] => Array
                    (
                        [Название] => Тележки ручные
                        [Код] => 8b3c2d19
                        [КодРодителя] => 8b3c2d10
                    )

            )

    )

[8b3c2d19] => Array
    (
        [Подразделы] => Array
            (
                [2e4744ac] => Array
                    (
                        [Название] => Тележки ручные ТП
                        [Код] => 2e4744ac
                        [КодРодителя] => 8b3c2d19
                    )

                [2e4744ae] => Array
                    (
                        [Название] => Тележки двухколесные
                        [Код] => 2e4744ae
                        [КодРодителя] => 8b3c2d19
                    )

            )

    )

[8b3c2d16] => Array
    (
        [Название] => Весовое оборудование
        [Код] => 8b3c2d16
    )

)
```